# Process 2 different files with camel

Tags: java, kotlin, apache-camel, camel-ftp

how can i read two different files with camel (using ftp) and write an unique JSON?
From what i know the "from" can only read one file.

```
from("ftp://myftp@localhost:21" +
                "/myFolder/" +
                "?" +
                "password=RAW(myPassword)" +
                "&include=file1.txt" +
                "&passiveMode=true" +
                "&delete=true")
            .log("Connected to FTP 1")
```

Comment: Hi! It's difficult to answer without a clearer understanding of what you're trying to do. You could use `aggregate` if you just want to read multiple files and accumulate the data before processing. You can use `pollEnrich` to read a second file if what you are trying to do read "file1b" to go with "file1a".

Comment: Hi, i have written an example of my code, could you make me an exaple of how would you implement what are you saying? Thank you very much

Comment: You still haven't explained how you determine the second file - is it just the next one in the queue, in which case @StepanShcherbakov's answer is your starting point. However, you have specified the file name for file1, so I assume you are wanting to join two specific files, not just the first two files you receive - how are you determining file2? If you explain what you are trying to achieve it will be easier to help you.

Comment: I have two different txt files, i want to read these two files and create a single json

Comment: OK - I get that - so when the first file is processed, how do you know what the second file will be? Is it dependent on the first file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is a `pollEnrich` pattern which would look something like this:

```
from("ftp:...&include=file1.txt...")
    .log("Connected to FTP 1")
    .pollEnrich("ftp:...&include=file2.txt...", new MyFileAggregationStrategy() )
```

or, if you need to specify a dynamic file name, like this:

```
from("ftp:...&include=file1.txt...")
    .log("Connected to FTP 1")
    .pollEnrich().simple("ftp:...&include=${header.file2Name}...")
        .aggregationStrategy( new MyFileAggregationStrategy() )
```

You will need to create an [AggregationStrategy](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/aggregate-eip.html#_about_aggregationstrategy), and that could either create your JSON directly, or you could sent the output to a processor that creates your JSON.

You will need to check the manual on [pollEnrich](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/pollEnrich-eip.html), to ensure you handle correctly what happens if a `file1.txt` appears without a corresponding `file2.txt`, so that it doesn't block unless you want it to (in which case you need to be able to handle nulls in your AggregationStrategy).

I hope this helps.

Comment: .aggregationStrategy don't exist

Comment: Apologies - I'd used a hybrid of two approached. It's corrected now.

Comment: I tried this, but second time pollenrich is not working.At first time-everything working as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own `AggregationStrategy` and use `aggregate(AggregationStrategy aggregationStrategy)` after `from` endpoint.
Here is documentation and some examples of [AggregationStrategy](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/aggregate-eip.html).

Comment: can you write me an example? I am trying to figure it out but i am not finding a way to do it. I am still confused about how to pick 2 files with different names and locations.

Comment: Sorry, i didnt recognize your problem. Your problem is to make json from 2 files from ftp or to read 2 different files from ftp?

Comment: I have two different txt files, i want to read these two files and create a single json